# How to use Masstransit's IBus in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq, moq, masstransit

I use Masstransit(v3.1.1) and RabbitMQ in my application. When I debug integration test or unit test; Masstransit doesn't publish my event.

I can't create a mock object from `IBus` to use it. Please help me how to create a mock object from `IBus` or how to use really `IBus` in a unit test with publish and consume message.

Comment: Please add code example which shows the way you are using Masstransit

Comment: Look at how the official tests are done, you can use the MassTransit.TestFramework in your unit test project: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/PublishSubscribe_Specs.cs#L24

Comment: Mocking `IBus` with NSubstitute (for example) is not an issue at all. It is hard to understand what do you mean by "can't create mock" since there is no code from you to look at.